# Scrapyd-deploy command not found after scrapyd installation

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, twisted, scrapyd

I have created a couple of web spiders that I intend to run simultaneously with scrapyd. I first successfully installed scrapyd in Ubuntu 14.04 using the command: 
pip install scrapyd, and when I run the command: scrapyd, I get the following output in the terminal:

```
2015-07-14 01:22:02-0400 [-] Log opened.
2015-07-14 01:22:02-0400 [-] twistd 13.2.0 (/usr/bin/python 2.7.6) starting up.
2015-07-14 01:22:02-0400 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.
2015-07-14 01:22:02-0400 [-] Site starting on 6800
2015-07-14 01:22:02-0400 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site instance at 0x7f762f4391b8>
2015-07-14 01:22:02-0400 [Launcher] Scrapyd 1.1.0 started: max_proc=8, runner='scrapyd.runner'
```

I believe that the fact that I got this output suggests that scrapy is working; however, when I run the command: scrapyd-deploy as in the [docs](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd-client), I get the error: scrapyd-deploy: command not found. How can this be possible if the installation was successful? I included the following target in the config file:

```
[deploy:scrapyd2]
url = http://scrapyd.mydomain.com/api/scrapyd/
username = name
password = secret
```

I'm not exactly sure how the target works, but I basically copied it from the docs so I would think that it would work. Is there something that I am supposed to import or configure that I haven't? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`scrapyd-deploy` is a part of [scrapyd-client](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd-client).You can install it from [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrapyd-client/). Try:

```
$ sudo pip install scrapyd-client
```

Comment: I wonder why the github page of scrapyd-client did not mention the way how to install it.

Comment: i installed scrapy with pip install scrapyd-client but scrapyd-client is still not found

Answer (score 1):

Can be installed from git directly:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd-client
```